# Combination Question with repetition and putting object back in pile

Tags: permutations, combinations

The question is as follows:

You have a pile of socks of which 8 are red and 3 are blue. You pick out 3 socks 1 at a time and each time you pick one out, you put the sock back into the pile before picking out the next. How many ways are there to pick out exactly 2 red socks?

What I think is that to pick 2 red socks out of the 8 there are 1 at a time, you would do 8C1 (8 choose 1: 8!/(1!(8-1!))) times 8C1. Since there is still one more sock to be chosen out of the blue, you would multiply that by 3C1.

Now here's the part I am not 100% sure about. Since this is not a normal combination question in which you are simply picking out a certain number of objects and forming a group (where order doesnt matter), would you have to multiply by 3 as well since there are three ways to pick out 2 reds.

1: rrb 
2: rbr
3: brr

I would think that since you are not actually making a group out of the items, rather you are taking them out 1 at a time and then putting them back, it matters the order in which you pick out the red socks. I imagine that picking out a red sock the first time, puttin it back, picking out a green one the second time, putting it back and then finally picking out another red sock is a completely different possibility than if you would have picked out 2 red socks at first and then 1 blue.

Final answer: 3 x 8C1 x 8C1 x 3C1 = 576

So is my logic correct and is this how you would answer the question?

Comment: If there were no replacement, the answer would be $\binom{8}{2}\binom{3}{1}$.  Since there is replacement, your answer $3 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 3 = 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 3 + 8 \cdot 3 \cdot 8 + 3 \cdot 8 \cdot 8$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also asked at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286101/12357).